# how do i remove a hashtag from multiple rows in r?

Tags: rstudio

I know that when I want to add a hashtag to multiple rows in R I use CTR+shift+c.
is there a way to remove a hashtag from multiple rows as well?

Comment: Use the same combo to add AND remove comment characters for multiple rows.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: ctrl+shift+c is used to add and to remove comment characters.